# Compiling bzip1 on a raspberry pi 2 with debian server?

Tags: compiling, gcc, bzip2

I've stumbled across the discontinued bzip-0.21 on the ftp of vim.org which is respectable, so I think it's fine.

However the code from 1996 won't compile anymore with today's GCC.

Is there a chance in getting it running for a modern device that requires the binary to be compiled for armhf?

Merely an enthusiast for old compression algorithms. The windows binary that was in the .tar.gz from the vim archive actually yielded smaller files than bzip2 when I made a test. Which is pretty impressive for such old code.

greetings
gavery

Edit:
the error was that **undefined reference to 'minUInt32'** references inside the c-file itself were not recognized by gcc in my case.

Comment: While C has changed some over the years, it has not changed that much.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to mention the errors you get? I’ve just rebuilt the `bzip` source with GCC 4.9.2 and 6.3.0, on armhf and arm64, and the resulting binary works fine. The build produces quite a few warnings but no errors.

Comment: Regarding the non-US thing, `bzip` was placed in the non-US Debian archive back in the day because “The algorithm uses arithmetic coding, so there might be problems with a patent in the USA.”

Comment: Without knowing the exact errors you’re getting, no one can help you fix your problem on the Pi — I can say “it works for me” but that doesn’t help you much (apart from moral support as you say).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by cross-compiling from a desktop PC:

**get the requirements**

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf gdb-multiarch -y
```

**build object code and compile**

```
ran@compilestation:~$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -O3 -g3 -Wall -c -o -fPIC "bzip.c"
ran@compilestation:~$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -o "bzip1" bzip1.o
```

**verify your work**

```
ran@compilestation:~$ file bzip1
bzip1: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=4cf52bccf817e031556bab923696f4677b00d29b, not stripped
```

(thanks to Stephen for mental support)